Changes in time_sleep in Terraform's CDK after manual cluster version upgrade
We have an EKS cluster configured by using this EKS module from Terraform.
Recently, we performed a manual upgrade of the cluster version from 1.28 to 1.31.
From this update, the Terraform state was behind the deployed infrastructure and was showing changes to configurations that were already in place. Notably changes in the EKS cluster version and in the node groups.
We refreshed the state and re-imported certain cluster resources successfully, fixing the drift, except for this one "time_sleep" resource:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with
the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
+/- create replacement and then destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.eks.time_sleep.this[0] must be replaced
+/- resource "time_sleep" "this" {
      ~ id              = "2024-04-03T15:10:33Z" -> (known after apply)
      ~ triggers        = { # forces replacement
          ~ "cluster_version"                    = "1.28" -> "1.31"
            # (3 unchanged elements hidden)
        }
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
    }


We've attempted the same methods as above, refreshing the state and attempting to import this resource, but unsuccessfully.
Is there any other way to sync/import this resource into the state, other than manually changing the state file? Is it best to just apply the changes? We're unsure if this would affect the EKS cluster in any way (downtime, etc.)?
